# Whether i can hit non public URL from Dialog flow through web hook?

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to use Dialogflow for my enterprise usage. So want to know whether Dialog flow will be able to hit Non public URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Since Dialogflow is a service hosted by Google, fulfillment requests specified by Webhook URLs must be able to be reached by Dialogflow for them to be invoked.  In addition, the webhook endpoints must expose themselves using SSL/TLS and must be associated with a non-self-signed certificate.  When a request is made from Dialogflow, dialogflow can provide authentication credentials to ensure that it is indeed Dialogflow that is making the request.

One pattern for your usage is to expose the Webhooks to the Internet and only allow connections from the Google IP address range and also require authentication (known only to Dialogflow).  This would go a long way in preventing malicious access to your Webhook.

An alternative would be to define your Webhook as a GCP hosted endpoint and then you would own the routing back to your internal system from there.  That could use a variety of technologies beyond HTTP including Pub/Sub.  For example, when Dialogflow invokes the Webhook, a GCP application could be called that posts a message to PubSub.  Your Enterprise application could be a subscriber and be notified that it has work to do.  It does work and responds with a new message which is received by your GCP hosted Webhook that then returns the response to Dialogflow.  As such, there is no surface area for an attacker to try and penetrate.